# How do you handle Nonetype while writing the values into a text file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am parsing an XML and extracting some data to write them into a text file. But, I get an error when I come across a Nonetype. How can we handle this in python?

Below is my code in the for loop where I write the values to the text file:

```
    line_to_write = description + ',' + original_address + ',' + translatedAddress + ',' + action + ',' + originalPort + ',' + translatedPort +'\n'
    with open('rules.txt','a') as f:
         f.write(line_to_write )
```

At this line in the output

100 None any x.x.x.x snat any any

I get this error

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: How do you *want* `None` to be represented in the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than concatenating strings with `+`, you should use string formatting. If you're using a newer version of Python (3.6+) you will probably want to use "f-strings":

```
line_to_write = f"{description},{original_address},{translatedAddress},{action},{originalPort},{translatedPort}\n"
with open('rules.txt','a') as f:
    f.write(line_to_write)
```

Comment: But those None values will be added rgt?

Comment: By default it will use the `__str__` representation for each object passed in. You can use the `__repr___` instead if you do `f{foo_bar!r}`. Likewise there are options for changing how numbers are represented, alignment, etc.